# Heuristic table converted to prolog facts highlight error

Tags: prolog

I have a Heuristc table with point `Node` & `H(n)` node value.
Am I correct below in converting to `prolog` facts?

It's giving me a yellow highlight `error` on all the captial letters i.e. (A,B,C,...)
Do they need to be changed to lowercase to be true?

```
% Heuristic table

/* Node   H(n)
 *  A     10
 *  B     5
 *  C     4
 *  D     8
 *  E     5
 *  G     0
 *  X     1
 */

%Table as facts

A(10).
B(5).
C(4).
D(8).
E(5).
G(0).
X(1).
```

Comment: I've just converted to lowercase letters and the errors have dissappeard, silly mistake!

Comment: Upper case as first letter in Prolog means it's a variable, then `A(10)` is a syntax error, for example. Changing to lower case will correct that issue and your representation is fine. However, it may not be most convenient depending upon how you want to reference the facts. Perhaps better would be, `node_h('A', 10).`, `node_h('B', 5).` etc (`'A'` is an atom since it's in single quotes). Or if you don't mind using lower case, `node_h(a, 10).` etc.

Comment: @lurker hi, I'm going to be referencing in dfs. So I also have a graph along with the heuristic table. Do they need to be chained together? Also, is it better to add the facts like you said, node_h('C', 4). or does it matter? As they're not variables, they're pre-defined node values. Thanks!

Comment: `'C'`, for example, is not a variable. It's an atom. If you easily want to query nodes by name versus heuristics, I would recommend `node_h(node_name, heuristic_value).` If you have nodes that linked like a graph, search this site for numerous posts about using Prolog to represent a graph. But basically you would have a fact for each node connection, such as `link(node_1, node_2).`. You can then write a predicate to follow its path.

Comment: V. nice reply. I understand the difference it defining it inside ' ' as opposed to a variable like C - on it's own. I will definetly look into it :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the facts need to start with lower case character.

Second, the way to present these truly depends on how you are going to use them.
If each fact is going to be called individually by its name, then something like the following will work:

```
a(10).
b(5).
c(4).
d(8).
e(5).
g(0).
x(1).
```

However, most probably you will need to process them in batches which means either creating a list of these facts and specify each fact by name OR use a generic fact form such as follows:

```
hnode(a,10).
hnode(b,5).
hnode(c,4).
hnode(d,8).
hnode(e,5).
hnode(g,0).
hnode(x,1).
```

Depending on your needs you may preferred using strings instead of atoms:

```
hnode("A",10).
hnode("B",5).
hnode("C",4).
hnode("C",8).
hnode("E",5).
hnode("G",0).
hnode("X",1).
```